# Is matlab on topic

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is a purely matlab-related question, like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11171/matlab-numden-does-not-simplify-by-lowest-common-factor, on topic?

**NB:** Asking this question initially required me to solve a captcha.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I don't see why not. It is likely to be something at least occasionally encountered by the targeted audience of this website. But we should at least point out to them that their question may not get many useful answers as it is probably not where the general expertise of the users are. And perhaps refer them to support forums for MatLab (such a thing exists, right? At least on USENET?)

Comment: The MathWorks site has a [forum for MATLAB users](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/), FWIW,

Comment: I've also gotten a lot of MATLAB questions answered on StackOverflow.